# is not a function in Angular 5

Tags: angular, function

I am going through a tutorial where we did following:

a class called shopping-cart:

```
import { ShoppingCartItem } from "./shopping-cart-item";
import { Product } from "./product";

export class ShoppingCart {

    items: ShoppingCartItem[] = [];

    constructor(public itemsMap: { [productId: string]: ShoppingCartItem }) {
        for (let productId in itemsMap) {
            let item = itemsMap[productId];
            this.items.push(new ShoppingCartItem(item.product, item.quantity));
        }
    }

    getQuantity(product: Product) {
        let item = this.itemsMap[product.key];
        return item ? item.quantity : 0;
    }
}
```

so if I try to access this function getQuantity in the html part via:

```
shoppingCartLol.getQuantity(productlol);
```

it says

> getQuantity is not a function in the console.

when I try it like

```
shoppingCartLol.items[productlol.key].quantity
```

it works!

So that means I have the right Object but I can't use the function? Can anyone explain this miracle to me?

Comment: I find the title bad

Comment: @JosiahKeller The default access modifier is public anyway I believe

Comment: @JosiahKeller already tried that, makes no difference

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin didn't know what I could use there buddy

Comment: Oops, you're both right.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz to reproduce please?

Comment: @user184994 I never did this I'll try :D

Comment: How is `shoppingCartLol` being initialized. If you're just assigning to it, then yeah, the `items` property exists, but the methods wont since you never initialized it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that sometimes the incremental compilation of my dev setup messes up (meaning its possible that the file being served does not have the `getQuantity()` method in it). Try completely stopping the dev server (`ctrl` + `c` on a mac) and restarting it (which should force everything to be recompiled).

Other things to try:

- replicating the problem code inside the class (aka outside of a template) and either starting a debugging session with a breakpoint (if your dev setup supports that) or console.log the object to make sure the object really is what you think it is.

  - For example, if you are deserializing your ShoppingCart from JSON, the resulting object might look very similar to an `instanceof` ShoppingCart (i.e. have all the same properties) while not being an `instanceof` ShoppingCart. And if its not an `instanceof` the class, it won't have the class' methods

Comment: @OcK well it certainly sounds like this just requires some detective work. I'd try replicating the problem code inside the class (aka outside of a template) and either starting a debugging session with a breakpoint (if your dev setup supports that) or `console.log` the object to make sure the object really is what you think it is. For example, It's POSSIBLE for some reason `shoppingCartLol` is a generic object containing `items`, rather than an instance of the ShoppingCart class.

Comment: @John That's a very good point, if the ShoppingCart is being deserialized from JSON this is almost certainly the issue

Comment: I tried console.log(this.shoppingCartLol) in the class constructor  where shoppingCartLol is a property and it says undefined! Hm but I'm still kind of lost here. So all the time I accessed another object?

Comment: I don't think us S.O. folks have enough info to say exactly--it depends on your code--but as @user184994 explained, ONE possibility is if you are deserializing your ShoppingCart from JSON, the resulting object might look very similar to an instanceof ShoppingCart (i.e. have all the same properties) while not being an instanceof ShoppingCart. And if its not an instanceof the class, it won't have the class' methods

Comment: @John I saw now that I never created a ShoppingCart via new ShoppingCart() ... so there is no this kind of Object there...

Comment: @OcK, ya it happens. That should be the problem then.